# Why does this shell script behaves differently with and without shebang?

Tags: shell

I'm following a linux shell programming guide to improve my proficiency with shell.
Today, I reached the section of nested for loops.

The following scripts prints a chessboard on terminal.

```
for (( i = 1; i <= 9; i++ )) ### Outer for loop ###
do
   for (( j = 1 ; j <= 9; j++ )) ### Inner for loop ###
   do
        tot=`expr $i + $j`
        tmp=`expr $tot % 2`
        if [ $tmp -eq 0 ]; then
            echo -e -n "\033[47m "
        else
            echo -e -n "\033[40m "
        fi
  done
 echo -e -n "\033[40m" #### set back background colour to black
 echo "" #### print the new line ###
done
```

And it works correctly.
Immediately, I added a shibang at the beginning of it and made it look like

```
#!/bin/sh
for (( i = 1; i <= 9; i++ )) ### Outer for loop ###
do
   for (( j = 1 ; j <= 9; j++ )) ### Inner for loop ###
   do
        tot=`expr $i + $j`
        tmp=`expr $tot % 2`
        if [ $tmp -eq 0 ]; then
            echo -e -n "\033[47m "
        else
            echo -e -n "\033[40m "
        fi
  done
 echo -e -n "\033[40m" #### set back background colour to black
 echo "" #### print the new line ###
done
```

Now, however, each white/black block is printed for a whole line.

Anyone can help me to understand why?
(I'm running the shell under Mac Snow Leopard).
Thanks!
William

---

gang:

Just an update, I found if I use "#!/bin/bash", it works fine.
So it's a problem of internal implementation of sh?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps your default shell is not `/bin/sh`? Try `echo $SHELL` and use the result in your hashbang.

Comment: Hi, Anders, you are correct. I just did it, and it's "/bin/bash"

Comment: `/bin/sh` is either a different shell or it is `bash` working in standards-compliant mode.  On my Mac, the files are slightly different in size (`/bin/sh` = 1371712, `/bin/bash` = 1371648), but they both report being 'GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)' when run with `--version`.  Look in the `bash` manual for information about what changes when you use `bash` as `/bin/sh` (in the `bash` 4.1 manual, mainly section 6.1 Bash POSIX Mode).

Answer (score 1):

`#!/bin/bash` perhaps?

You put `#!` when you want to specified which program will be used to interprete this text file

Comment: yep. that works fine. Does this looks like a difference in shell program implementation? Or it's some sort of a bug :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are using `echo` but this command behavior is unfortunately not predictable, even on POSIX compliant systems.

When `-n` is passed as `echo` parameter or when an escape sequence is present in the argument, echo behavior is unspecified. Your code is using both of these non portable constructions. Moreover, it is also using the non portable `-e` bashism.

Have a look to the ["APPLICATION USAGE" chapter in the echo POSIX manual page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/echo.html#tag_04_41_16) for details.

You should use `printf` instead of `echo`. `printf` is portable and has been created to overcome `echo` limitations.

```
#!/bin/sh
for (( i = 1; i <= 9; i++ )) ### Outer for loop ###
do
   for (( j = 1 ; j <= 9; j++ )) ### Inner for loop ###
   do
        tot=`expr $i + $j`
        tmp=`expr $tot % 2`
        if [ $tmp -eq 0 ]; then
            printf "\033[47m "
        else
            printf "\033[40m "
        fi
  done
 printf "\033[40m" #### set back background colour to black
 echo "" #### print the new line ###
done
```

By the way, this code could be simplified that way (works with at least both ksh and bash):

```
for (( i = 1; i <= 9; i++ )); do
  for (( j = 1 ; j <= 9; j++ )); do
    printf "\033[%dm " $((((i+j)%2)?40:47))
  done
  printf "\033[40m\n"
done
```

Comment: What do you mean by echo is not predictable?

Answer (score -1):

`echo` is a shell builtin (though it's also available standalone in `/bin/echo`) so depending on the version of your shell it may behave differently. On my system (OS X Mountain Lion):

```
$ which sh
/bin/sh
$ /bin/sh --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.37(2)-release (i386-apple-darwin12.2.0)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
$ /bin/sh -c "echo -e -n '\e[0;34mtest'"
-e -n \e[0;34mtest   # incorrect

$ which bash
/opt/local/bin/bash
$ /opt/local/bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.37(2)-release (i386-apple-darwin12.2.0)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...
$ /opt/local/bin/bash -c "echo -e -n '\e[0;34mtest'"
test    # blue and without a newline. correct
```

So on my Mac `/bin/sh` does not support either of the `-e` or `-n` arguments, while `/opt/local/bin/bash` does, similar to what you're seeing.

BTW you can do the calculation with the `$(( ... ))` arithmetic expansion, or with `let`:

```bsh
# with arithmetic expansion:
tmp=$(( (i + j) % 2 ))   # $i and $j can be used but are not necessary

# with let:
let tmp=(i+j)%2   # no spaces allowed

# or just calculate inside the if statement directly:
if (( (i + j) % 2 == 0 )); then
....
```